# German language simulator for training verbal skills

Tags: learning, online-resource, spoken-language

I have started to learn German language and seem to be doing okay when it comes to understanding the grammar and writing any texts. Where I am miserable lacking is when it comes to verbal skills as I have no one to interact in German language therefore I am unable to gain confidence. Is there in an online German language simulator which can help me out solve verbal problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Livemocha](http://livemocha.com)? From their website:

> The world’s largest online language learning community, Livemocha fuses traditional learning methods with online practice and interaction with native language speakers from around the world

There you'll have the oportunity to interact with native speakers and watch them engage in conversations.

P.S. It's free!

Comment: @gmauch- Thanks a lot!! I haven't tried it but will do so!!